# @helper method equivalent in aspx

Tags: asp.net, helper

Is it possible to create reusable code blocks in an HTML page? I have a table that I want to replicate multiple times in my aspx page and I don't want to duplicate the code.
I've used @helper in Razor before but I don't know of an equivalent tag in aspx.

Answer (score 2):

WebForms and MVC works in very different manners.. In WebForms you create a WebControl, not  HtmlHelpers

Here is a tutorial about how to develop a server control in Asp.Net:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx